# How to get rid of html conflict

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I'm using tinyMCE editor to post my message and if I entered any **list type message** or manually entered any `div` or `li` or `ul` items using tinyMCE, if I listed the message sent list it leads me to design conflict...

I'm using `strip_tags` like:

```
echo strip_tags($message,'</ul></li></p>');
```

But even though I got the same issue, can anyone help me solve that? My message listing is like this:

```
<ul><?php 
foreach($messages as $message)
{  ?>
 <li><?php 
     echo strip_tags($message,'</ul></li></p>');
     ?>
  </li>
}?>
</ul>
```

My message will be like this

```
$message = "
<ul>
    <li>Gautam</li>
    <li>S.Visser</li>
    <li>DaggNabbit</li>
</ul>";
```

Comment: Why whould you allow `</ul></li></p>` those tags ?

Comment: Because only those tags Iam using through timyMCE editor..

Comment: Can you give us an example of the data in `$message`?

Comment: S.Visser see my edit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `$message` whould be this:

```
Gautam</li>
S.Visser</li>
DaggNabbit</li>
</ul>
```

What makes the html output:

```
<ul>
 <li>Gautam</li>
    S.Visser</li>
    DaggNabbit</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What makes it incorrect html.

I'm not fully sure what you trying to accomplish but I think if you use `striptags` like this:

`echo strip_tags($message,'<ul><li><p></ul></li></p>');`

You should get correct html.

Comment: I'm agree too with this answer, why don't you try it?

Comment: Thanks It is working for me...and I have also put an answer to my own question....can u see and tell me the comment..??

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with **html_entity_decode** and it is also working ...I tried like this

```
<ul>
<?php 
   foreach($messages as $message)
   {  
      echo "<li>";
      echo html_entity_decode($message);
      echo "</li>";
   }
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have broken your script... I've fixed the syntax

```
<ul>
<?php 
foreach($messages as $message)
{  
    echo "<li>";
    echo strip_tags($message,'</ul></li></p>');
    echo "</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Is that what you wanted?